# Android MAVEN creating a ApkLib from a non maven project

Tags: android, maven

I am looking to install a third party android library project to my local repository. I zipped the file up and renamed it to mylib.apklib. I then

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=myfile.apklib
```

This gives me the following error

```
 The artifact information is incomplete or not valid:
  [0]  'groupId' is missing.
  [1]  'artifactId' is missing.
  [2]  'packaging' is missing.
  [3]  'version' is missing.
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Check out [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html) to see how to use install:install-file goal.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
 mvn install:install-file \
      -DgroupId=org.abc \
      -DartifactId=mywidget \
      -Dpackaging=apklib \
      -Dversion=1.0.0 \
      -Dfile=mylib.apklib \
      -DgeneratePom=true
```